# Finding the Heading of a Turtle Vec2D

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I was making a vector in the turtle module of python in order to control the movement of a turtle. I was wondering if it was possible to be able to find the angle of rotation of the vector in order to use for the rotation of the turtle. I want to find the angle of rotation from one of the endpoints. Thanks for an help.

Answer (score 0):

A Vec2D instance only contains X & Y values.  To know which way a turtle is heading, you need a third orientation value that's contained within the turtle itself, not in the Vec2D.  (Technically, you probably need to know the ***tilt*** as well but that's rarely used.)

The ***rotation*** of a Vec2D is relative to the angle it makes with the origin, unrelated to the heading of the turle.  For example, we can draw a square this way, ignoring the heading of the turtle:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle('turtle')

yertle.goto(200, 200)

for _ in range(4):
    yertle.goto(yertle.position().rotate(90))

screen.exitonclick()
```

Simply by rotating a Vec2D's position relative to the orgin.  The angle the Vec2D makes with respect to the origin is called its ***argument*** but I don't see any Vec2D method to obtain it.  [This vector package](https://gist.github.com/mcleonard/5351452) has one we can modify for our purpose:

```
import math
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.mode('logo')

def argument(self):
    """ Returns the argument of the vector, the angle clockwise from 0."""
    arg_in_rad = math.acos(self[1] / abs(self))
    arg_in_deg = math.degrees(arg_in_rad)
    if self[0] < 0:
        return 360 - arg_in_deg
    return arg_in_deg

yertle = Turtle('turtle')

yertle.goto(200, 200)

for _ in range(4):
    print(argument(yertle.position()))
    yertle.goto(yertle.position().rotate(90))

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note that I used `mode('logo')` to simplify my math since we've no specific purpose in mind for this code.  Although this will print out the angle of the turtle's position relative to the origin, it tells us nothing about the heading of the turtle should we execute a `forward()` command.

If you want to record and/or playback turtle movements, you could make your own data structure that incorporates a Vec2D and the orientation of the turtle.

However, one way around keeping the orientation of the turtle, and just using a list of Vec2D positions, is when you set the turtle's position to a Vec2D position in the list, use the combination `turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(position))` on the ***next*** Vec2D position in the list.  That way the turtle is always heading (facing) towards its next location:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

positions = [(-3.0, 10.0), (-2.0, 13.0), (0.0, 17.0), (5.0, 23.0), (6.0, 24.0),
    (11.0, 27.0), (22.0, 30.0), (49.0, 31.0), (72.0, 26.0), (116.0, 3.0),
    (135.0, -31.0), (132.0, -52.0), (128.0, -65.0), (122.0, -84.0),
    (109.0, -118.0), (82.0, -158.0), (20.0, -188.0), (-52.0, -181.0),
    (-132.0, -136.0), (-213.0, -45.0), (-244.0, 97.0), (-206.0, 225.0)]

screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle('turtle')

for target, position in enumerate(positions, start=1):
    yertle.goto(position)

    if target < len(positions):
        yertle.setheading(yertle.towards(positions[target]))


screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: So is there no way to calculate the angle of rotation of the vector?

Comment: @rbhog, relative to the origin (or some other arbitary point) sure.  But the rotation of the vector isn't the heading of the turtle.  Two different things.  For a turtle follwing a path, the heading of the turtle is towards the next position in the path.

Comment: What I was trying to figure out was how to find the angle of rotation in comparison to an arbitrary point to set the heading of the turtle to it in another command.

Comment: @rbhog, augment your question above with more information and whatever code you have so far to help determine what might be possible.